# Summation Elixir

Tags: algorithm, math, elixir

I am trying to recreate this equation in Elixir:

[image]

For now I am working on an easy example and I have something like this:

`Enum.each(1..2, fn x -> :math.pow(1 + 1/1, -x) end)`

However, while using Enum.each I am getting an :ok output, and therefore I can't inject it later to Enum.sum()

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum.each/2` is for side effects, but does not return a transformed list.

You are looking for [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2).

Alternatively, you could use a `for` comprehension:
`for x <- 1..2, do: :math.pow(1 + 1/1, -x)`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! However, when you say 'alternatively' do you imply that it's a worse approach?

Comment: No sorry, I didn't mean that :) Both approaches are equivalent, but since you were asking about `Enum` I put this as a first approach.

Answer (score 4):

While the answer by @sabiwara is perfectly correct, one’d better either use [`Stream.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#map/2) to avoid building the intermediate list that might be huge, or directly [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) to the answer.

```elixir
#                 ⇓ initial value
Enum.reduce(1..2, 0, &:math.pow(1 + 1/1, -&1) + &2)
```

Comment: In some of the benchmarks I did in the past, streams could end up being actually less efficient than the enum version for [this specific use case](https://github.com/sabiwara/enumancer/blob/main/bench/map_sum.results.txt), which is why I did not mention them. But good point about directly reducing, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @sabiwara yeah, `Stream`s are well-known to be slower, but not _as_ performance-killing as instantiating or the huge intermediate list, which is absolutely likely to happen here (it’s a series calculus after all.)

Comment: I'm not so sure in practice. I tried to [benchmark again on big ranges](https://github.com/sabiwara/enumancer/blob/1359e978f06c112ab175f1bc4da8f169b4b3dc18/bench/map_sum.results.txt) and the memory usage seems notably higher for streams (I guess because streams create a lot of tuples under the hood, which might be more costly than the list itself?). Anyway, `reduce/3` is the clear winner for this case :)

Comment: Indeed, `reduce/3` is the clear winner in nearly each and every case :)